# angular 9 candeactivate not working although code seems to be fine and not throwing any error

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-cli, angular-router-guards, candeactivate

Hello Guys I am new to Angular and learning the things using the following tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WveRq-tlb6I&list=PL6n9fhu94yhXwcl3a6rIfAI7QmGYIkfK5&index=39). For some reason the canDeactivate route guard seem to not work. Any help would be appreciated as I tried checking many things but none worked. I have the latest angular CLI and there are not errors in my code and for some reason the canDeactivate function is not at all called during the route change.

I am applying the function on the CreateEmployee route so when I fill the form for createEmployee and I try to navigate to different route then it should kick in.

**create-employee-component.html**: In this, I have few form elements

```
<form #employeeForm = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="saveEmployee()" [ngClass]="{'was-validated': employeeForm.submitted}" novalidate>
```

**create-employee-component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Department } from '../models/department.model';
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { Employee } from '../models/employee.model';
import { EmployeeService } from './employee.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-employee',
  templateUrl: './create-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-employee.component.css']
})
export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('employeeForm') public createEmployeeForm: NgForm;
    datePickerConfig: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;
    previewPhoto = false;
```

**create-employee-can-deactivate-guard.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent  } from './create-employee.component';

@Injectable()
export class CreateEmployeeCanDeactivateGuardService implements CanDeactivate<CreateEmployeeComponent>{
    canDeactivate(component: CreateEmployeeComponent): boolean{
        alert("HJEJJEJEJ");
        if(component.createEmployeeForm.dirty)
        {
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ListEmployeesComponent } from './employees/list-employees.component';
import { CreateEmployeeComponent } from './employees/create-employee.component';
import { CreateEmployeeCanDeactivateGuardService } from './employees/create-employee-can-deactivate-guard.service';


const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'list', component: ListEmployeesComponent},
    {
        path:'create', 
        component: CreateEmployeeComponent,
        canDeactivate: [CreateEmployeeCanDeactivateGuardService]
    },
    {path: '', redirectTo:'/list', pathMatch:'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [CreateEmployeeCanDeactivateGuardService]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I feel everything is correct as per some of the other answers I found on the StackOverflow. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. I have also posted my code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ap9abm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts).

Comment: Hi Batman, can u create a demo on https://stackblitz.com/. That would help me debug and investigate the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will create and provide you the link.

Comment: Hello again. Please find the link to my project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ap9abm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Comment: Hi, the code link does not seem to be working and is not bootstraping.  Can you please make it work .

Comment: Hi, Just now I tried it seems to be working fine. Can you please once try again?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ap9abm

Comment: I am using the date picket option for the Date Of Birth field but now I have removed that field can you please once check now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was the issue. After some time spending on the research I found out that in the navbar previously I was using the href element with the anchor tag hence the `canDeactivate` guard was not kicking in. Now I changed it to `[routerLink]="['/list']"` and the `canDeactivate` started working correctly.

Posting the answer as it may be useful for someone who is looking for solution:

Previous Navbar with the anchor tag and `href` element:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="list">List <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

Changed Navbar with the anchor tag and `routerLink` which is working fine with the `canDeactivate`:

```
<a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/list']">List <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
```

If in case you are looking for the whole code please check the question where I have mentioned all the code chunks related to `canDeactivate` guard.